# java RTFEditorKit : chaining blocks of text

Tags: java, text, block, jeditorpane, chained

I need to chain blocks of text in a *java* desktop application. These blocks of text are in `JTextPane`. The editor associated with the JTextPane is the `RTFEditorKit`.

My problem is to detect when the current text is no more visible by the user in order to transfer the current word at the end of the block of text to the next chained text block.

My idea was to used the `DocumentFilter` associated with the RTFEditorKit in order to detect when the transfer has to be made. But I do not know how to **detect** that the current text is at the end of the **visible** part of the JTextPane. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Did something similar in the past (linked textboxes to let text flow)
You have size of JEditorPane (width and height) anf you can get preferred size for the fixed width (see [here](http://java-sl.com/tip_text_height_measuring.html)). If the preferred size is bigger than height you have overflow.

Another way is to use viewToModel() method. JUst pass bottom right corner pixel and get offset. If the offset is less than the Document's length overflow is detected.

Comment: I used your first one method but the result is not perfect. I would like trying to use the viewToModel

Comment: I would like trying to use the viewToModel method but I can't arrive to get the offset for the bottom right corner pixel. Can you help me ?  Thanks in advance